# Obtaining the list format of a binary matrix

Tags: regex, notepad++

Suppose we have a large binary matrix in  Notepad++ as follows:

```
0 0 1
1 1 0
0 1 0
```

My question:

I need to find a command in the "regular expression" such that the output of the binary matrix be in the following form

```
[0 0 1]
[1 1 0]
[0 1 0]
```

In other words, my problem is how to put `[` in the first of digits and also put `]` at the end of the digits. I've done this manually so far.

Thanks for any help

Edit: Based on the comments the question is edited.

Comment: When you say "you need to find" you actually mean "we need to find it for you"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why downvote, please let me know its reason. Thanks for your contribution in the question.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @Samuel The question has been edited according to your comment. My problem is how to put "[" in the first digits and also put "]" at the end of the digits. I've done this manually so far.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The question has been edited according to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)$`
- Replace with: `[$1]`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (.+)      # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions. It is really an interesting answer.

Comment: @user0410: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: You were kind to me. Thank you.